# How to use LO datatype with postgresql?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

What I'm currently trying to do:

I am using a software with Postgresql as the backend DB. The software supplies an API that uses a web service to communicate with the software/DB. I am trying to insert an image to the database through the api, which normally should be a BLOB, since postgresql doesn't support that, I created the lo extension with the postgresql-contrib package. Now, that the actual large objects are kept in it's own table, and the current table just keeps a reference to that object, however the API does not account for this. I currently have the datatype for the image column as a BYTEA, but I get an error saying "Column 'img' is of type bytea but expression is of type lo;". There is not much I can do within the API since the insertion is encapsulated in the backend of the webservice. Is there something I can do in Postgres itself to allow the api to insert large objects?

TL;DR:

Software API expects to put in large object (BLOB) to DB. Should work seamlessly if the DB recognizes the BLOB datatype.
I've set up the lo extension in postgres.
Currently I set the column datatype to bytea but get this error:
"Column 'img' is of type bytea but expression is of type lo;".

How do I store lo's?

:::I'm using postgresql 9.1

---

I got it working. After dropping the tables, I forgot to re-create the lo extension, which is why it wasn't recognizing the datatype.

Comment: `lo` and `bytea` storages are compleatly diffrent. You do not need `lo` extension to store `bytea` and you cant store `lo` to `bytea` column

Comment: I understand that, but how do I store a lo?

Comment: If you want to store images (or any other files) in DB - just use `bytea` and forget `lo`. The only benefits `lo` has over `bytea` are 2 GB file size limit (vs 1 GB) and ability to do random acces on `lo` files.

Comment: If you really want to store `lo` objects - define the column with type `lo` (instead of `bytea`) to store this object. But you will have to manage `lo` objects separately as they are not deleated, when the row with `lo` column is deleated.

Comment: I get: 'column "img" cannot be cast to type lo'

Comment: Drop it and recreate.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko, thanks for all your previous help, is there a script on the server side that I can run to obtain the large objects, rather than using client side java code?

Comment: You can use `psql` as command line tool to write scripts. `psql` scripts can do anything you want with a DB.

Answer (score 1):

The easyes (but not the most eficient) way to transfer files to db is to encode files into `HEX` or `base64` transfer them as `varchar` and `decode` into `bytea` type before storing into `bytea` field.

Same way you retrive files from db.

If you want to transfer `bytea` without encode/decode owerhead - then you have to study how you driver, language and framework can handle it.

Comment: unfortunately, this isn't an option because the software's webservice sends off the images as a lo and only as a lo.

Comment: @JHP I havent heard about a software, that knows postgres `lo` type. Are you talking about postgres special `lo` type or general BLOBS ?